# Discord.JS Deleting a message if it contains a certain word

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I am trying too add moderation too my bot and since my server is fully SFW I am trying too make it so that my bot will delete a message if it contains an NSFW word, Here is my code. Im not sure if its correct but It is not working so I would imagine its not

```
message.content.includes === ("<Insert NSFW message or word here>")
message.delete(1)
```

Im still looking for help  btw

Comment: Without an `if()` statement `message.content.includes === ("<Insert NSFW message or word here>")` is useless by itself

Comment: Oh yeah, I havent made a bot in a while lol

Comment: @charlietfl It's useless anyway, `.includes` is a function - I think you mean `message.content.includes(<word>)`

Comment: @awarrier99 right...wasn't paying attention to the name and was looking at it as an object property

Answer (score 1):

You are doing great so far,

First I would you should create an array of NSFW words that you want to be censored

**Ex:**

```
const noNoWords = ["sex", "condum"];
```

After you have done that you should irritate through the array and see if the message's content includes the a NSFW word

**Ex:**

```
const noNoWords = ["sex", "condum"];

client.on("message", message => {
    var content = message.content;

    for (var i = 0; i < noNoWords.length; i++) {
        if (content.includes(noNoWords[i])){  
            message.delete();
            break
        }
    }
}
```

That works and all but if people type CAPS it wouldn't detect, or if people put in spaces, like t h i s. In order to fix this we need to remove all special characters and make the string lower case.

**Ex:**

```
var stringToCheck = content;
stringToCheck.replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase();
```

Then you plug it in and it should look like this :)

```
const noNoWords = ["sex", "condum"];

client.on("message", message => {
    var content = message.content;
    var stringToCheck = content.replace(/\s+/g, '').toLowerCase();

    for (var i = 0; i < noNoWords.length; i++) {
        if (content.includes(noNoWords[i])){  
            message.delete();
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but it has an error ` } ^ SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list`

Answer (score 0):

```js
if (message.content.includes("<Insert NSFW message or word here>"))
message.delete(1)
```